# Configuring a custom CA in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: certificate, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

Could somebody please point me in the right direction for configuring Hyperledger Fabric to use a custom CA. The docs [here](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html?highlight=certificate%20authority%20#hyperledger-fabric-ca)  suggest that any CA that support ECDSA can be used.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the Cryptogen tool. 
It produces x509 certificates, and this can be used by you to prime the fabric network entities (orderer, peers, clients).
I recommend you run cryptogen to produce the needed PEM files by reading [byfn](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html) (take a look at *./byfn.sh -m generate* )
If you can replicate this folder structure you're good to go.

Additionally (this is just a thought, never tried it), Fabric-CA has an HTTP API for registering clients. 
If you build your own gateway that mocks Fabric-CA's API and does the same things - you can make the client SDK (which includes also a fabric-ca client) talk with your CA as if it was Fabric-CA

Comment: Thanks for this. I think I might take a look at mocking the Fabric-CA API. Our solution already has REST API so a bit of middleware should do the trick I would hope.

Comment: Are there any plans to build on the hooks for external CA's? I suspect for most enterprises this will be a requirement.

Comment: Not a clue. You can ask in https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/fabric-ca

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand very well the aim of your question. However, I'm going to answer it.

> right direction for configuring Hyperleger Fabric to use a custom CA

Hyperledger Fabric needs some certificates to control and restrict the acces to the Blockchain. For each channel you define who members are going to be part of it, and you configure the [MSP](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/msp.html?highlight=msp). The certificates are used for the [MSP](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/msp.html?highlight=msp). So, you can create those certificaes in any way, then you should pass them to the corresponding members and locate them in the corresponding directories.

However, Hyperledger Fabric gives you the chance to achieve it:

1. On the one hand, as @yacovm said, by using the cryptogen tool
2. On the other hand, as you said, by creating your own CA Authorithy, i.e. by your own CA Server